# How to use Android_ID to communicate with other device?

Tags: android, networking, android-wifi

My router shows

```
14:AA:BB:CC:DD:46  android-################  192.168.3.112
AC:AA:BB:CC:FF:46  MY-LAPTOP  192.168.3.112
AC:AA:BB:CC:FF:AC  NAS  192.168.3.112
```

Now if I use `ftp://NAS/` it works, but 
if I use `ftp://android-################:7721/` it does not work, again `ftp:/192.168.3.112:7721/` works, I don't understand what is the use of Android_ID then.

I thought since Android IP keeps varying on router we can find android by using Android_ID, but that's not the case.

Can anyone explain why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

Your Android device uses DHCP to get an IP address from the router on your network. While a router will try to use the same IP address across sessions, there's no guarantee you'll always be handed the same IP address. You generally do not want to make any assumptions about it not changing.

Assuming you have client software that's trying to talk to a service running on the Android device you need to implement some sort of network discovery mechanism. Android has a mechanism in the SDK that uses mDNS called "NSD". See https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd. You could also use UDP broadcast.

"android-####" is a local hostname. Unless you have registered your Android device with a DNS server serving your local network you need to use IP addresses (and in that case you'd need to configure your router to also give your Android device the same IP address).